# Add column entry if certain date, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I am using the dataframe below and am attempting to add a new column containing a Note depending on a few conditions.

Condition 1: Spend = Y

Condition 2: Ccy= Mgd Ccy

Condition 3: If the date is today+1 add 'Note 1' to a notes column, if the date is today+2 add 'Note 2' to a notes column

Any help is appreciated x

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUl1D.png)

Comment: df.where, np.where, np.select

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Amount': [1, 2, 3], 'Ccy': ['EUR', 'EUR', 'CHF'], 'Mgd Ccy': ['EUR', 'EUR', 'EUR'], 'Spend': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y'], 'Date':pd.date_range("2021-08-17", periods=3, freq="D")})
df = df[(df['Date'] == (pd.datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")) | (df['Date'] == (pd.datetime.now() + timedelta(days=2)).strftime("%Y/%m/%d") ) ]
df['new_column'] = np.where((df.Spend == 'Y') & (df['Ccy'] == df['Mgd Ccy']) & (df['Date'] == (pd.datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")), 'Note 1', 'Note 2')
df
```

The result is :

| Amount | Ccy | Mgd Ccy | Spend | Date | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | EUR | EUR | Y | 2021-08-18 | Note 1 |
| 3 | CHF | EUR | Y | 2021-08-19 | Note 2 |

Comment: im trying to only populate cells where the date in that row is either 18th or 19th, so ideally first row would be blank, second row contains Note1 and third row contain Note2

Comment: @BrianTheMoose I rectify the code ;)
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to make sure that the Date column is `datetime` via:

```
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
```

Then, subtract the desired dates and add extract the differences in days:

```
data['Differences'] = (data['Date'] - pd.Timestamp('today')).dt.days
```

Finally, perform some conditional selection with the general format of `data.loc[conditions, column_name]`:

```
data.loc[(data['Spend'] == 'Y') & (data['Ccy'] == data['Mgd Ccy']),
         'notes'] = data['Differences'].apply(lambda x: 'Note ' + str(x))
```